# How can I access system information from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, system, sandbox, execute

I want to get information - like the number of monitors the client is using. I need access to system calls and I understand that since the browser is sandboxed, it can't execute sys calls.

What other options do I have to do this (other than the client installing an app on the desktop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this can be done using extensions. Chrome allows for access to such information through its "activeTab", "tabs", and "system.display" permissions found here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.

In general, extensions allow the website to have more control over the visiting computer and access to data to/from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible, because it's not safe for users to allow this kind of information.

Some info about sys is available in navigator object. A good start to check what you need there.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like the objects do not allow such information.

Comment: The thing is, inside the browser you can access few things...